# Cant do software Updates on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, updates

I keep getting this Update notification and everytime I try to update I get the error message below...Please help and comment if more information is needed. Thank you in advance

[image: Screen Shot 1 is Error Message]

[image: Screen shot 2 is the update notification]

Comment: Have you tried ran `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: I just tried it how you have it typed out vs the way the error message has it written and then did the updates and it seems to be working now THANK YOU SO MUCH...THIS is the answer so repost it as the answer so i can give you the up vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time you face with similiar situation, the first thing to do is ran `apt-get -f install` as this is the very basic fix attempt offered by apt.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

**`sudo apt-get -f install`**:
The `-f` option stand for `--fix-broken`, means `apt` will attempt to `--fix`ing unmet dependencies by satisfy them. Pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you again for your help...lol i have been messing with ubuntu for years but nothing major... I just made the full switch from windows 7 to ubuntu on my desktop and have run into a few different issues but it is an exciting learning experiance...like re learnign how to use a computer

Comment: Also this helped me to get discord running properly which i was having issues with