# I cant install any software, keeps throwing error

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I can't install any program or software, for example I tried Dropbox from their official web. When i try install using `sudo dpkg -i`, it won't let me because there are dependencies error.

Comment: A dependency error is not a system error. The system is trying to tell you (the human) that you have instructed it to do something unwise or impossible. Since you have not provided any details yet, we cannot determine what mistake you made.

Comment: Probably unmet dependencies error, in that case `apt-get -f install` should fix it. And yeah, he needs to paste the full error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know what those error refer to, unless you paste the code to here. Please do that..

However, you mention the error has to do with dependencies, in that case try running `apt-get -f install`.

> **`sudo apt-get -f install`**: The `-f` option stand for `--fix-broken`, means `apt` will attempt to `--fix`ing unmet
>   dependencies by satisfy them.

<sub>[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/964113)</sub>

If you prefer GUI, there's also `gdebi` which install `.deb` file (and the required dependencies), I've been using this tools for year and never failed me.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Comment: thank you, i type that on terminal and it seems to be working now, thankss

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!